# Listener not called by p:ajax on p:inputText

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to implement custom filtering on a p:dataTable. In the header of the dataTable, I have a p:inputText that I want to filter the table via ajax. The problem I am having is that the bean method is not being called by the p:ajax tag. Here is the offending code snippet:

```
   <h:form id="form1">
        <p:dataTable id="selectTable" var="select"
           selectionMode="multiple" rowKey="#{select.id}" 
           value="#{pc_Selectcourses.allCourses}">
           <f:facet name="header">
              <p:outputPanel>
                 Search For Courses Completed:
                 <p:inputText id="filterEntry" value="#{pc_Selectcourses.query}">
                    <p:ajax event="keyup" update=":form1:selectTable"
                       listener="#{pc_Selectcourses.filterListener}" />
                 </p:inputText>
              </p:outputPanel>
           </f:facet>
           <!-- table columns here, etc. -->
       </p:dataTable>
   </h:form>
```

And the backing bean:

```
public void filterListener() {
   System.out.println("Hello world, hope you're listening...");
}
```

When I type in the inputText, the Sysout is never printed. I also notice that my ajax notifier/status icon doesn't show any activity, so I doubt anything is happening.

**Edit**

I just tried dragging and dropping p:ajax from Eclipse's Palette into my xhtml code and it said to use this I needed to import libraries into my workspace. I let it go ahead and it added primefaces v3.2 jar file into Web_INF/lib. The p:ajax still doesn't work.

I am confused as to why it asked for this as all the Primefaces components have been working great all along. Is there possibly something wrong with the project setup?

Comment: Your inputtext has no value attribute. Is it a copy/paste issue?

Comment: Yeah, I accidentally removed it while pasting the question. I edited the question to reflect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this same problem today.  It turns out that in your backing bean, if you have a getter function for `query` but NOT a setter function, p:ajax won't call its listener.  Since you didn't post that section of your Java code, I assume there's a good chance this is your problem.